# Changing the timezone in libc time at compile time

Tags: c, time, libc

We have firmware that will be deployed on devices all over the world and that will be synced to UTC by a host device. To track time, we end up converting between `struct tm` and `time_t` (Unix time) because we use a hardware RTC whose registers closely mirror `struct tm`, but any time-based operations are done on Unix time. However, when we use `mktime` it attempts to put everything into `localtime`, which is not UTC on the build system. We could just add an offset, but it would be easier to just tell `time.h` that our local time should be UTC, since the device is otherwise agnostic to the local time.

Is there a (non-invasive) way to do this other than changing the local time on the build system to UTC? Like, can we somehow use `tzset` to inject this data? Or just set `TZ` to something? I'm having difficulty understanding how I would set `TZ` if I just wanted UTC.

Comment: I think I answered my own question and I can just add `TZ=UTC` to the beginning of my build command in CMake, but I will leave it open in case there is a better way.

Comment: wouldn't it be more appropriate to use `gmtime` instead if you need UTC time?

Comment: Don't understand the problem. Set up your hardware RTC to track UTC. Done. Build system time or timezone are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes actually it looks like we (inanely) have been feeding the test harness data that comes from a local time, which was the cause of our perceived problem. On the device, once we write UTC to the RTC, everything shakes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when we use `mktime` it attempts to put everything into `localtime` ...

The compiler's time zone setting at *compile* time is irrelevant to how code handles time at *run* time.

The *easiest* way to avoid local time in conversions is to hope your compiler offers `struct_tm` (UTC) to `time_t`, instead of using `mktime()` (time zone dependent) as an extension like [`time_t timegm(struct tm *tm)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timegm).

There is no simple *standard* solution.  Tricks with divining the offset via `locatime(), gmtime()` fail corner cases.

---

IMO, to convert `struct_tm` (UTC) to UNIX time `time_t`, simply write that code and get it reviewed.  It is not that hard as there are few corner cases (aside from overflow).

Some sample code to change `int year, int month, int day` (0:00:00)  to [MJD](https://web.archive.org/web/20130214020649/http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/mjd.html) to get OP started.

```
#include <stdint.h>
static const short DaysMarch1ToBeginingOfMonth[12] = { //
    0, 31, 61, 92, 122, 153, 184, 214, 245, 275, 306, 337};
#ifndef INT32_C
#define INT32_C(x) ((int_least32_t)1*(x))
#endif
#define DaysPer400Years   (INT32_C(365)*400 + 97)
#define DaysPer100Years   (INT32_C(365)*100 + 24)
#define DaysPer4Years     (365*4    +  1)
#define DaysPer1Year      365
#define MonthsPerYear     12
#define MonthsPer400Years (12*400)
#define MonthMarch        3
#define mjdOffset         0xA5BE1
#define mjd1900Jan1       15020
// November 17, 1858

// Example: 2015 December 31 -->  ymd_to_mjd(2015, 12, 31)
int2x ymd_to_mjd(int year, int month, int day) {
  // int2x is a type twice as wide as int to handle extreme int values.
  // Use int (at least 32-bit) to handle common values.
  int2x year2x = year;

  year2x += month / MonthsPerYear;
  month %= MonthsPerYear;
  // Adjust for month/year to Mar ... Feb
  while (month < MonthMarch) {
    month += MonthsPerYear;
    year2x--;
  }

  int2x d = (year2x / 400) * DaysPer400Years;
  int y400 = (int) (year2x % 400);
  d += (y400 / 100) * DaysPer100Years;
  int y100 = y400 % 100;
  d += (y100 / 4) * DaysPer4Years;
  int y4 = y100 % 4;
  d += y4 * DaysPer1Year;
  d += DaysMarch1ToBeginingOfMonth[month - MonthMarch];
  d += day;
  // November 17, 1858 == MJD 0
  d--;
  d -= mjdOffset;
  return d;
}
```